# Error running filter pandoc-citeproc when specifying csl style

Tags: haskell, markdown, pandoc

I'm on a MacOSX 10.9. I've just installed the latest haskell and pandoc, pandoc-citeproc and run updates via cabal update. I'm running Xcode 4.6.3.

I'm trying to convert a markdown document to docx or any other format. I'm using a .bib file for the bibliography and all works fine if I don't specify the reference style csl. However, as soon as I try to specify a csl, nothing works. I've uninstalled and reinstalled everything including Haskell and all packages and still no luck. I've tried putting the csl in different folders and specifying their location as well.

Here's the error I get consistently:

> pandoc-citeproc: error while reading the XML file: XMLParseError "not
>   well-formed (invalid token)" (XMLParseLocation {xmlLineNumber = 28,
>   xmlColumnNumber = 71, xmlByteIndex = 1627, xmlByteCount = 0}) pandoc:
>   Error running filter pandoc-citeproc

I'm hoping this is something simple I've overlooked but I've tried everything!!

Any help would be much appreciated - I'm at my wits end!

Comment: Wow - after 24 hours working on resolving this it was all to do with the csl file. Saving the csl from github didn't work (still not sure what I'm doing wrong there), but when I did from the Zotero site it did. Very much a rookie mistake as I'm new to github. Apologies for the time wasting.

Comment: Note that the styles from GitHub and the Zotero Style Repository are practically identical (except for the embedded timestamp). Just make sure you save the raw file (e.g., https://raw.github.com/citation-style-language/styles/master/apa.csl ).

Comment: Hmmm. I just had the same problem with the same fix (thanks @user2986904). Haven't investigated why, but I am pretty sure I had saved the raw file as per @rintze-zelle